# mercurial (hg) syntax equivalent of git's "^", meaning the commit PRIOR to the specified commit

Tags: git, mercurial

In git, for a given commit X, X^ means the commit prior to X.

Is there an hg equivalent?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [parentrevspec](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ParentrevspecExtension) extension is bundled with mercurial, but extensions are not activated by default.  You'll need to edit the exensions section of your hgrc.

```
[extensions]
parentrevspec =
```